# Are cars in Arizona melting in the 2018 summer heat?

Tags: united-states, road-vehicles, environment

Facebook just posted to my timeline this picture claiming that cars in Arizona are melting in the heat.

Is it true?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80058/discussion-on-question-by-pieter-geerkens-are-cars-in-arizona-melting-in-the-201).

Comment: The text is given with a smiley - the person was just making an obvious joke.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence so I can only comment, but I was (still am) in Tempe, Arizona. I took this picture in the Starbucks parking lot off University and Forest on June 28, 2018.  So no whole cars weren't melting, but parts of some were... https://i.imgur.com/kYHCOoL.png All the seals on my 2011 Accord have also become a disgusting mess of gunk

Answer (score 258, accepted):

The weather is not melting cars.  But there was a big fire in Tucson and the heat from the fire melted plastic parts on a bunch of cars in the parking lot.  [The pictures in this article](http://www.tucsonnewsnow.com/story/38472657/cars-owners-dealing-with-melted-cars-from-construction-fire) fairly clearly match the cars, parking lot, and background building in the picture you attached.

So, are cars in Arizona melting in the heat?  A few that were unfortunately parked near a building that caught on fire.  Did it have anything to do with the weather?  No.

Comment: The 6th image in the article contains the car on the left side in the above image.

Comment: @ErikE the picture at the top is a slideshow. Mouse over (or touch on mobile) the sides of the image to flip between them.

Comment: I think more impressive (in the sense of both size and economic loss) pictures in this aritcle are the melted construction cranes.

Comment: @DoktorJ Sheesh. I kept clicking the photo at the top of the text. It doesn't have any slideshow there. The photo at the very top of the page, though... I was skipping over that because it just seemed like a static header to me. It had so little "information scent" for me. If the title of the article was *above* those, I am 100% sure I would have seen them.

Comment: It's also obvious from the parts of the car that are scorched/damaged most, the heat was directional - specifically, behind the camera.

Comment: PS: the car in the 1st image in the article is the one on the left side in the above image.

Comment: In some rare cases, reflections from windows or other lense-type objects can cause melting or warping to some plastics. The softening/melting point of the most heavily used car plastics range from about ~220°f (abs) and ~300°f (polycarbonate)...which is well above even the hottest standard outdoor temperatures.

Comment: It looks like there are traces of incomplete combustion on the rim of the car on the right.

Comment: @heyitsmyusername [like this?](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2786723/London-skyscraper-Walkie-Talkie-melted-cars-reflecting-sunlight-fitted-shading.html)

Answer (score 34):

A search on https://tineye.com led me to [this tweet by @AyeElleJay](https://twitter.com/AyeElleJay/status/1010154502861869057?s=19) with the caption "Slimmmmm! Arizona weather real different " against that image.

Replies to the tweet questioned its validity, and a user named @TheMutHouse replied "this is from a recent fire in tucson, the neighboring apartment buildings cars were melted."

I'm not sure if it's the source of the image but a local news site does indeed have [a story titled "Owners dealing with melted cars after construction fire"](http://m.tucsonnewsnow.com/story/38472657/cars-owners-dealing-with-melted-cars-from-construction-fire).